# What do the SObject.clone(preserveId, isDeepClone, preserveReadonlyTimestamps, preserveAutonumber) method parameters do?

Tags: sobject, clone

At Apex code while cloning the record:

```
clone(preserveId, isDeepClone, preserveReadonlyTimestamps, preserveAutonumber)
```

Need to know the each parameter how does it work.

```
Contact obj = new Contact(Id ='0035i00002jSn1qAAC', LastName = 'Nadie Person', Email = 'nadp@stores.com');
Contact clonedContact = obj.clone(true, true, false, false);
System.debug('==================='+clonedContact);
insert clonedContact;
```

If we make the first one parameter as true then it shows an error. Does anyone know about the parameter work (preserveId , isDeepClone).

Comment: I've downvoted this because this is literally what [the official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_clone) is for. If you ever have a question about methods in a class that Salesforce provides, then the official Developer Documentation should be the first thing you look for. Using your search engine of choice and plugging in `<class name> class apex` (e.g. "SObject class apex") usually gets you to the developer docs in the first few results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `preserveId`

When `true`, the cloned copy will retain the `Id` field. This makes the clone suitable for upsert, update, and delete operations. When `false`, the cloned copy will have a `null` value in the `Id` field, suitable for inserting a new record.

```
Contact c1 = new Contact(LastName='Fear');
insert c1;

Contact c2 = c1.clone(true, true, false, false);
c2.FirstName = 'Brian';
update c2; // Updates existing record with new values

c2 = c1.clone(false, true, false, false);
insert c2; // creates a duplicate record with FirstName=Brian, LastName=Fear
```

## `isDeepClone`

When `true`, the cloned copy will copy any related objects from the record. This means that altering a related value will not affect the original value. The clone will consume additional memory.

When `false`, the cloned copy will not create new objects in memory, so modifying a related object also affects the original. The cloned object will take up less memory, since the related objects are not copied.

```
Contact c1 = new Contact(LastName='Fear', Account=new Account(Name='Fear Household'));
Contact c2 = c1.clone(true, true, false, false);
c2.Account.Name = 'Fear Household Updated';
Assert.areNotEqual(c1.Account.Name, c2.Account.Name); // passes

c2 = c1.clone(true, false, false, false);
c2.Account.Name = 'Fear Household Updated';
Assert.areEqual(c1.Account.Name, c2.Account.Name); // passes
```

## `preserveReadonlyTimestamps`

When `true`, copies the CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate, and SystemModStamp fields. When `false`, those fields are set to null in the clone. Set this to `false` to avoid errors on DML operations when these values are set in the original record.

## `preserveAutonumber`

When `true`, copies the value in an auto-number field. Otherwise, the values are nulled out. Set this to `false` to avoid errors on DML operations when these fields are set in the original record.

Comment: Thanks for update. It was a great help @sfdcfox